# formating date output in sql server

Tags: sql-server, date

I have `nvarchar(255)` column in my table.
And data is in format of `9/4/2013`

```
SELECT 
      YEAR([Last Revision Date]) + '-'+ 
      MONTH([Last Revision Date]) + '-'+ 
      DAY([Last Revision Date])
FROM  events_tbl
```

Individual, they are good, but I want to put them in 1 column when doing SELECT statement

So for date:`9/4/2013`

gives me: `2026`

And I want `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: would you believe me if I told you that that convert with 126 doesn't work for me? lol

Comment: it returns same format it was in to start with: 9/4/2013. I tried everything and splitting it like the above, works

Comment: @Angelina See my answer, you have to cast your column as a `DATE` or `DATETIME` before using that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast your column as a `DATE`, then you can use the `CONVERT` function to convert the date to your desired format.

This should do it:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), CAST([Last Revision Date] AS DATE),126)
FROM events_tbl
```

**[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b88a/1)**

Comment: ahhhh. It was a CAST... It worked...Thank you @Khan